# Scaling using libjpegturbo in java

Tags: java, libjpeg-turbo, turbojpeg

I have an image that I want to re-scale the size so that the file size will be small. By using libjpegturbo class `TJScalingFactor` and `TJCompressor`, I am still unable to re-scale the image as there is no method which allow height and width to be inputted.

Comment: Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: i am able to use TJScalingFactor class to .getscaled() both height and width but there is no method in TJCompressor that require the input of the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be somehow related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146434/can-a-high-performance-jpeglib-turbo-implmentation-decompress-compress-in-100ms), where the OP wants to compress, decompress and compress an image to scale it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488048/libjpeg-output-scaling) is also talking about scaling while decompressing, what can in fact be done with the TurboJPEG API.

**This part contains background information**

In fact, scaling while compressing was only introduced and implemented in the version 7 of the Independent JPEG Groups libjpeg. The developer of TurboJPEG and libjpeg-turbo [has doubts about the usefulness](http://www.libjpeg-turbo.org/About/SmartScale) of this new function, why he does not see any reason to implement it. Also, the [project page](http://www.libjpeg-turbo.org/About/TurboJPEG) says: "It can also optionally be configured to be API/ABI-compatible with libjpeg v7 and v8, but it does not include support for the non-standard SmartScale format introduced in libjpeg v8."

**TL;DR;**

Use `TJCompressor` to compress the image, decompress it with the wished width/height using `TJDecompressor` and compress it again using `TJCompressor`.